# "kdb5_util create" fails with an error

Tags: centos-6, kerberos

krb5-server 1.10.3-33.el6 on CentOS 6.5.

I'm following the [Red Hat KDC Instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Smart_Cards/Configuring_a_Kerberos_5_Server.html). Right there at the start, the instructions give me `/usr/sbin/kdb5_util create -s`. If I run that, I get this:

```
#  /usr/sbin/kdb5_util create -s
Loading random data
Initializing database '/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/principal' for realm 'EXAMPLE.COM',
master key name 'K/M@EXAMPLE.COM'
You will be prompted for the database Master Password.
It is important that you NOT FORGET this password.
Enter KDC database master key: 
Re-enter KDC database master key to verify: 
kdb5_util: Required parameters in kdc.conf missing while initializing the Kerberos admin interface
```

(Yes, I've changed `EXAMPLE.COM` to something appropriate for my environment.)

Here are the contents of `/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf`. The contents are out of the box, with two exceptions. I've uncommented the `master_key_type = aes256-cts` line, and I've narrowed down the `supported_enctypes`. I did check, and the global `aes` encryption type includes `aes256-cts`.

```
[kdcdefaults]
 kdc_ports = 88
 kdc_tcp_ports = 88

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  master_key_type = aes256-cts
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  admin_keytab = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
  supported_enctypes = aes:special aes:normal des3:special des3:normal
 }
```

The syntax for the `supported_enctypes` is consistent with [the documentation](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/www/krb5-current/doc/admins/index.html).

The exact "Required parameters..." error string doesn't show up in a Google search. I'm going to experiment with the encoding types, to see if I've messed that up despite the documentation. I did note that the salt called `special` is "[not fully supported](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.8/krb5-1.8.5/doc/krb5-admin.html#Salts)." So, yes, I will be paying particular attention to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after several iterations, this worked. The problem was that the `aes` encryption group doesn't seem to work in `supported_enctypes`. The encryption types have to be specified individually. (I also added a logging section, thinking that was the problem. A cross check later ruled that out. It was just the `aes` "bundle".)

```
[kdcdefaults]
 kdc_ports = 88
 kdc_tcp_ports = 88

[realms]
 EXAMPLE.COM = {
  master_key_type = aes256-cts
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  admin_keytab = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
  supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:special aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:special aes128-cts:normal des3:special des3:normal
 }

[logging]
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc/kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc/kadmin.log
```